# Python/Pip broken after updating to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, python, python3, pip

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.
Before I did, I could use pip(3) and pipenv to install modules.
Now I find that whatever I try, I get errors.
The only thing that does work is to call pip(3) as a module in python...

For Python (2.7):

```
bokkie@Vidar:~$ which python
  /usr/bin/python

bokkie@Vidar:~$ which pip
  /usr/bin/pip

bokkie@Vidar:~$ pip -V bash:
  /usr/local/bin/pip: Bestand of map bestaat niet

bokkie@Vidar:~$ python -m pip -V
  pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

For Python3 (3.6)

```
bokkie@Vidar:~$ which python3
  /usr/bin/python3

bokkie@Vidar:~$ which pip3
  /usr/local/bin/pip3

bokkie@Vidar:~$ pip3 -V
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

bokkie@Vidar:~$ python3 -m pip -V
  pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

My Path:

```
bokkie@Vidar:~$ echo $PATH
/home/bokkie/bin:/home/bokkie/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I'm the only user on this PC.
`Python` and `Python3` both respond still, but `pip` and `pip3` are no longer stand-alone.

Neither is `pipenv`:

```
bokkie@Vidar:~$ pipenv install TKinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 7, in <module>
    from pipenv import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipenv'
```

*(Tkinter used as example)*

What can I do to fix this seemingly broken system?
Or is this supposed to work this way now?